# Javascript show error when date chosen is lesser than current date

Tags: javascript

I need help for the JavaScript code to validate the date which is two days after the current date. Example like office staff holiday application form. I want to set for the staff who wish to submit their holiday form. The holiday starting date applied should be at least 2 days from the date of application. If the staff apply 1 day before or a date earlier than the date of application, a error message will appear and the textbox will be cleared. Please help me for the JavaScript code and the way to put it in PHP. Thank you.

Comment: You should take a look at moment.js: http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: You won't get an answer telling you how to do it all. Do some research than ask when you're stuck, once you've tried something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)' relative time for do this.

Moment.js is simple and easy to use. Try it!